# How can I make Visual Studio Code use Visual Studio IDE key bindings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I love all of the major default key bindings of Visual Studio IDE for C++ development, such as block selection (ALT+SHIFT+ARROWS), selecting by jumping words (CTRL+SHIFT+ARROWS), and so on.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio Code to use the IDE keybindings? Or is this something I have to set up myself, by hand (I hope not)?

Comment: Did you ever get the "traditional VS" key bindings for code? I would love a copy if so!

Comment: Sadly, I have yet to find a pre-made keybindings file for this. I've slowly been changing key bindings as I go for my own personal use, but it's FAR from comprehensive.

Comment: How is this not something Microsoft want to make available? Um. Cheers anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the *Visual Studio Keymap* extension by going to *File* > *Preferences* > *Migrate Keyboard Shortcuts from...* in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thanks! As of the current version of Visual Studio Code, the extension is available via _File > Preferences > Migrate Keyboard Shortcuts from..._

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of vscode's default keybindings here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings

If you don't like the default keybindings, you can override them by updating your `keybindings.json` file as noted on that page.